# AJAX Search doesn't return accurate results when trying fast

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm using NonFactors.Mvc.Grid with a search.  Unless I'm overlooking something obvious, I'm implementing it [as shown here](http://mvc-grid.azurewebsites.net/Grid/GlobalSearch).

In the parent view, I have this line that generates the grid:

```
@Html.AjaxGrid(Url.Action("UserSearch", new { }))
```

I have the search textbox:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.WildCardSearch, new { @class = "form-control per90 mt5 mr5 pull-left", placeholder = "Search", autofocus = "autofocus" })<i class="fa fa-125 fa-search"></i>
```

Which ends up generating this:

```
<input 
    autofocus="autofocus" 
    class="form-control per90 mt5 mr5 pull-left" 
    id="WildCardSearch" 
    name="WildCardSearch" 
    placeholder="Search" 
    type="text" 
    value="">
```

This is the client-side method that handles it:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#WildCardSearch', function () {
    $('.mvc-grid').mvcgrid({
        query: 'search=' + this.value,
        reload: true
    });
});
```

And this is the server side method that does the search:

```
public PartialViewResult UserSearch(string search)
{
    var results = // Initial query that returns an IQueryable of all the raw results. 

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
    {
        search = search.ToLower();
        results = from r in results
                  let bothNames = r.LastName + ", " + r.FirstName
                  where
                   r.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(search) ||
                   r.LastName.ToLower().Contains(search) ||
                   bothNames.ToLower().Contains(search) ||
                   r.Phone.Contains(search) ||
                   r.Email.Contains(search)
                  select r;
        }
        return PartialView(results);
}
```

Now, here's the thing....

If I type VERY SLOWLY in the search textbox, and wait for each keypress to process, then the results are always 100% accurate.  BUT, if I type fast, then the results end up being all over the board.  Sometimes that are accurate, but most of the time they are not.

Comment: Maybe not something that solves the original problem but I would recommend to throttle the ajax calls until the user stops writing.

Comment: Have no idea about control you use, but problem indicates that old results are sometimes come from server faster than newer, and so old results (say related to "te" search) overwrite newer (related to "test").

Comment: You need to ensure that the user has stopped typing before you search. I would place a timer on my search function to wait for x (500ms). On key up, check if timer has started and start it and also RESET x to 500ms. So for every key up, the timer is reset to 500ms. The search will then run 500ms after your last key up. (dont forget to stop timer when you call the search function.

Answer (score 0):

By hunting and pecking across multiple threads, I came up with this solution:

```
<script>

//setup before functions
var typingTimer;                //timer identifier
var doneTypingInterval = 1000;  //time 1 seconds

//on keyup, start the countdown
$('#WildCardSearch').on("keyup", function () {
    if (typingTimer) clearTimeout(typingTimer);                 // Clear if already set     
    typingTimer = setTimeout(DoTheSearch, doneTypingInterval);
});

//on keydown, clear the countdown 
$('#WildCardSearch').on("keydown", function () {
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
});

function DoTheSearch() {
   ... ajax call to the server
}

</script>
```

Comment: While this approach is fine, note that it is still subject to the same problem, though to much lesser extent. To solve it completely you need to either disable input while search is running, or discard search results if current search does not match them (better).

Comment: How would one do this: discard search results if current search does not match them

Comment: You make ajax query and pass some search term there, suppose you pass "te". When results from this query come, you check if original search term is the same as current. Suppose user typed "test" when results came. You see that "te" not equal "test" and discard results of this query.